# php working in localhost but not in server?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi i have one html and php file,in that html i have one textbox and button and when we click the button it call the php file and through post method it pass the text to php and from there with the help of "INSERT" query it added to db. but all these working fine in local host under htdocs folder. NOw i have uploaded that php file to my server and run that html from my desktop its not working.any idea??

php code

```
<?php 
  $con = mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","dbname");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $te=$_POST["test"];
  mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO comment_page (comments) VALUES ('$te')");
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: define "not working"...

Comment: when i click button in html page i can see the php code but values are not added

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL code, read up on [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You cannot simply slam `$_POST` data into your query.

Answer (score 2):

> when i click button in html page i can see the php code but values are not added

If you can see PHP code that means your web server is not configured to run PHP yet, simple as that. Install and/or configure PHP on your web server.

**Edit**

> NOw i have uploaded that php file to my server and run that html from my desktop its not working.any idea

Desktop?? You don't run PHP files on desktop by just double clicking on them. If you mean your html is on the desktop and your PHP is on the server then in your form's action provide the complete url of your PHP page.

Comment: and is this line correct??  <form action="form.php" method="post">  html in ddesktop and form.php in server

Comment: You cant run from desktop! it has to be loaded via HTTP that PHP

Comment: so i need to install php ??

Comment: On server, yes it needs to have PHP if you want it to run PHP codes